# Tab key moves down instead of right in Excel

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-excel

When I use the Tab key while in Excel, the cell moves down instead of to the right.
How can I get the active cell to move to the right when the tab key is pressed?

Comment: Cool. Do you have a question or were you just sharing?

Comment: In my excel, it moves to the right. By any chance the columns on the right are locked?

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in the comment above, generally the focus should move to the right. The only instance when it moves down is when the columns on the right are locked and the worksheet protected.

If you worksheet is not protected and you are still facing that problem then here is a VBA Code which can help you achieve what you want.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SettabKey()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}", "MoveDown"
End Sub

Sub MoveDown()
    If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then _
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Select
End Sub
```

To reset it use `Application.OnKey "{TAB}"`

Answer (score 0):

Please note this is not for the latest versions of office. You didnt specify.

> Go to Tool | Option | Edit |
> Move selection after enter
> Change the direction to Down
>
> [Source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/15589-redirecting-tab-key-go-down.html)

The office website has information on this as well, although it states there is no way to change the direction of tab within the program [Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/move-the-cursor-after-entering-data-HP005199274.aspx).

I expect it is possible to use VBA to do this however although I do not have the skills required to build the function.

Comment: That only affects what happens after hitting enter, not tab.

Comment: thanks. I just used a quick search to find that info. Have updated answer with info from MS Office site.